# Centring all content

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms

I am a beginner in ASP.NET and C Sharp. I have been trying to centre all the text boxes and labels inside the white box so everything is in the centre. I have tried various solutions however nothing seems to be working. I would highly appreciate any solutions to fix this. As well as allowing space under each text box so it doesn't look so clustered together. Thank You!
[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>SB Admin 2 - Register</title>

    <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
    <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i"
        rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
    <link href="css/sb-admin-2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   
</head>

<body class="bg-gradient-primary">
      <form id="user" runat="server">
   
    <section class="vh-100" style="background-color: #2779e2;">
  <div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
      <div class="col-xl-9">

        <h1 class="text-white mb-4">Apply for a job</h1>
          <div class="card" style="border-radius: 15px;">
          <div class="card-body">

            <div class="row align-items-center pt-4 pb-3">
              <div class="col-md-3 ps-5">
  

        <table class="auto-style6">
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style7">
            <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" class="mb-0" runat="server" Text="First Name" ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <div class="col-md-9 pe-5">
        <td class="auto-style8">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" class="form-control form-control-lg" runat="server" Width="297px"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqFieldFN" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Your First Name!" BackColor="Red" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Dashed" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" ControlToValidate="txtFirstName"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
       
            </td>
    </tr>
            
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style7">
            <asp:Label ID="lblLastName" class="mb-0" runat="server" Text="Last Name" ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style8">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" class="form-control form-control-lg" runat="server" Width="295px"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqFieldLN" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Your Last Name!" BackColor="Red" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Dashed" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" ControlToValidate="txtLastName"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
            

            <div class="row align-items-center py-3">
              <div class="col-md-3 ps-5">
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style7">
            <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" class="mb-0" runat="server" Text="Email" ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        </div>
        <td class="auto-style8">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="example@example.com" runat="server" Width="294px"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqFieldEmail" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Your Email!" BackColor="Red" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Dashed" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="White" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" Font-Bold="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
                
            <div class="row align-items-center py-3">
              <div class="col-md-3 ps-5">
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style7">
            
            <asp:Label ID="Password" class="mb-0" runat="server" Text="Password" ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style8">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" class="form-control form-control-lg" runat="server" Width="293px"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqFieldPass" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter A Password!" BackColor="Red" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Dashed" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="White" ControlToValidate="txtPassword" Font-Bold="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style7">
            <asp:Button ID="btnRegister" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" runat="server" OnClick="btnRegister_Click" Text="Register" />
        </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

to center everything easily just use the grid, for example:

```
.vh-100{
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
  }
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for responding. However where do I place this? and when I put this into the document, it comes up as "Place-Items" is not a known CSS property name. I don't understand

Comment: Can anyone help?

Comment: it's "place-items"....lowercase

Comment: yes but where does it go?

Comment: it goes after display : grid;

Comment: steve i meant this whole piece of code you are advising where does it go within my code???

Comment: it goes in vh-100

Comment: Steve it doesnt work